# How can I ensure the correct display of Japanese and other foreign characters obtained from the MetaApi get() method?

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

I'm encountering an issue with encoding foreign characters when retrieving metadata using VLCJ in a JavaFX music player application.

This is the code I use to obtain media metadata (such as title and album) after having prepared and parsed the media:

```
@Override
public void mediaPlayerReady(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    long length = mediaPlayer.status().length();
    String formattedTotalDuration = StringFormatter.formatDuration(Duration.millis(length));
    MetaApi meta = mediaPlayer.media().meta();

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        playbackController.setLblDuration(formattedTotalDuration);
        playbackController.setLblSongName(meta.get(Meta.TITLE));
        playbackController.setLblSongArtist(meta.get(Meta.ARTIST));
        playbackController.setLblSongAlbum(meta.get(Meta.ALBUM));
        playbackController.setCoverArt(new Image(meta.get(Meta.ARTWORK_URL)));

    });
}
```

The problem manifests when attempting to display titles, artists, and albums that include characters from languages like Japanese. For instance, `meta.get(Meta.TITLE)` for a song with the title "01.私と浪漫ていすと" returns �?�?�浪漫�?��?��?��?� on the console and is displayed like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ermyA.png). On the contrary, text that doesn't include foreign characters is processed correctly as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qy71.png).

I would like to know if there is any way to ensure that the text returned by the MetaAPI is encoded correctly. I've tried setting the following system property `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");` as well as applying the UTF-8 encoding manually to `meta.get(Meta.TITLE)`, but none have worked. Maybe the issue isn't encoding?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

My Java version: 21
VLCJ version: 4.8.2
Windows 11

UPDATE:

I looked into how to detect text encoding as suggested by @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I wrote `meta.get(Meta.TITLE)` to a txt and got its encoding using juniversalchardet and its UniversalDetector:

```
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class StringEncodingConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Detect text encoding
            String filePath = "C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents\\juniversalcharset\\data.txt";
            Charset detectedCharset = detectCharset(filePath);
            if (detectedCharset != null) {
                System.out.println(detectedCharset.toString()); // <- Got 'UTF-8'
                // Convert to Unicode

                String unicodeText = convertToUnicode(filePath, detectedCharset);
                System.out.println("Converted text:\n" + unicodeText);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to detect text encoding.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private static Charset detectCharset(String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath); BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {

            UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
                detector.handleData(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            detector.dataEnd();
            String charsetName = detector.getDetectedCharset();
            if (charsetName != null) {
                return Charset.forName(charsetName);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String convertToUnicode(String filePath, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath); InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, charset); BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }
     

            return result.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out that the text returned by the MediaAPI was already UTF-8. As expected, converting it to UTF-8 made no difference. Unfortunately, taking a string from the `meta.get()` and passing it through a UniversalDetector directly gave me the same results. I'm no expert at all, but this leads me to believe that perhaps something is wrong with the metadata itself and how it is processed.

UPDATE 2

I forgot to mention that I used to use jaudiotagger-3.0.1 to obtain metadata from songs before, and it worked as expected. I switched to using VLCJ's MetaAPI in an attempt to make my project more cohesive and decrease the number of dependencies, in addition to increasing performance by avoiding creating File instances for every song. In the worst case, I may go back to using it.

Comment: You're going to have to make sure to convert everything you work with to Unicode, and that's probably going to require converting from "not Unicode". Japanese files (in)famously use JIS (ISO-2022-JP), not UTF-8, but the more modern the file, the more likely it _will_ already use UTF-8, so... you're looking at "how can I detect text encoding and convert to unicode in Java", really =(

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you so much for the lead! It sounds challenging, but I'll look into that. Have a nice day!

Comment: [UTF-8 was made default in Java 18](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400), so I advise using Java 21+.  Then, at least you know the default encoding processed by Java is UTF-8, and you don't have to try to override the default anywhere for that to take effect.  Of course, as Mike points out, if the input is not UTF-8, then you will need to do a conversion.  If you want to display the text in a UI, then you also need to use a font that can render the appropriate characters for the language.

Comment: If you use jlink or jpackage for packaging, you also need to ensure the appropriate localization pack is bundled (see [`--include-locales`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jlink.html#plugin-include-locales))

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks, I appreciate the info. I didn't know about UTF-8 being the default Java 18 onwards. I forgot to mention that I'm using Java 21, so I'll add that and the version of vlcj I'm using on an edit. Regarding the font I'm using in my app's UI (Roboto), it can render Japanese characters. I'm using a TreeView to display filenames, and they do indeed display properly.
My project is modular, and I do use jlink, so I'll check if I'm using the correct localization pack.

Comment: I added `--add-modules jdk.localedata --include-locales=en,ja,es` as VM arguments, and included `requires jdk.localedata;` in my module-info, but sadly it didn't work

Comment: Creating a label like `new Label("私と浪漫ていすと")` displays the characters correctly using JavaFX 21.0.2 with Java 21.0.2 on Windows 10. That makes me suspect the problem is on vlcj's end. [This issue](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/1198) mentions a problem with subtitles and encoding on 4.8.2, though it seems the issue originated with the latest version of "native-streams". Maybe that's the source of your problem, too? If not, could you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: *"01.私と浪漫ていすと" returns �?�?�浪漫�?��?��?��?� on the console* On *which* console? cmd.exe doesn't properly support Unicode, so you'd be better off with Powershell

Comment: @g00se Regardless of shell, you have to be using the correct code page if you want Unicode characters to display correctly. You can change it to UTF-8 with `chcp 65001`. On PowerShell Core, I _also_ had to execute `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8` for characters to display correctly.

Comment: Meant `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8` (though both do the same thing).

Comment: @g00se, @Slaw I apologize for not clarifying in the post. I meant the output in the Netbeans console that was returned by a `System.out.println(meta.get(Meta.TITLE))` I used for debugging purposes. It serves no use outside of that, which is why I didn't include it in the snippet. Regardless, I appreciate the guidance on how to display Unicode characters on Powershell

Comment: @Slaw _This issue mentions a problem with subtitles and encoding on 4.8.2, though it seems the issue originated with the latest version of "native-streams"._

I searched through the dependencies of my project but couldn't find native-streams. I'll investigate the matter further and check caprica's vlcj-player.
_If not, could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?_ 
Yes, I'll update my post with a MRE as soon as I can. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Slaw thank you all so much for your help! I was able to find the solution. Please take a look at the newest update I wrote.

Comment: Ah, so it's a JNA issue? Also, note the better place to put your solution would be in an answer (you should have enough reputation now to self-answer).

Comment: @Slaw You're right, I'll do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256684/discussion-between-greattusk-and-slaw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a vlcj/native-streams issue specifically, rather it became a problem when the JNA dependency version that vlcj and native-streams use got bumped to a version newer than 5.9.0.

With JNA 5.9.0, the strings are not garbled, but switching to 5.10.0 (or later) will lead to garbled strings.

This change in JNA is a possible reason - "Update native encoding detection for JEP400", https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/1393

This is the code in JNA from 5.9.0, in `Native.java`:

```java
    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.defaultCharset();
    public static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = Native.DEFAULT_CHARSET.name();
```

This is the code in JNA from 5.10.0:

```java
static {
    // JNA used the defaultCharset to determine which encoding to use when
    // converting strings to native char*. The defaultCharset is set from
    // the system property file.encoding. Up to JDK 17 its value defaulted
    // to the system default encoding. From JDK 18 onwards its default value
    // changed to UTF-8.
    // JDK 18+ exposes the native encoding as the new system property
    // native.encoding, prior versions don't have that property and will
    // report NULL for it.
    // The algorithm is simple: If native.encoding is set, it will be used
    // else the original implementation of Charset#defaultCharset is used
    String nativeEncoding = System.getProperty("native.encoding");
    Charset nativeCharset = null;
    if (nativeEncoding != null) {
        try {
            nativeCharset = Charset.forName(nativeEncoding);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Failed to get charset for native.encoding 
value : '" + nativeEncoding + "'", ex);
        }
    }
    if (nativeCharset == null) {
        nativeCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    }
    DEFAULT_CHARSET = nativeCharset;
    DEFAULT_ENCODING = nativeCharset.name();
}
```

You are using JDK version 21, so you would be impacted by this new code.

You should check the value of the `native.encoding` environment variable when your program runs, and explicitly set the value to "UTF-8" if it is not that already.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to express my gratitude to everyone who commented and guided me to the solution. @Slaw pointed out a [Github issue](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/1198) on vlcj's repository where another user had experienced a similar problem with subtitle descriptions. They had identified that the source of the garbled text was the version of native-streams, which appears to be a dependency of jna.

After taking a look at caprica's  [vlcj-player](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player), I tried replicating the present issue, by playing the same song as before and displaying its title in the status panel.  [As you can see, 私と浪漫ていすと was properly rendered](https://imgur.com/a/oylveXM). Seeing as the libraries were the potential source of the seemingly corrupted text in my project, I grabbed:

```
jna-5.5.0.jar
jna-platform-5.12.1.jar
native-streams-2.0.0.jar
vlcj-4.8.0.jar
vlcj-natives-4.8.0.jar
```

from [vlcj-player](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player) and replaced the ones I'd previously been using (I'd like to add that I'd downloaded those from [this page](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/4.8.2)). This, in hindsight, was not a prudent decision.

After compiling and running my project, [the previously unintelligible text rendered successfully](https://imgur.com/a/oKF1dTk).

In conclusion, the lesson I've learned here is to get the libraries I use from official sources. I would like to express my gratitude once again to everyone for their assistance; I would not have been able to solve this issue on my own.

Comment: Often it is a good idea to use a build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle) and source dependencies using that, from standard repositories like Maven central.  For instance [vlcj is hosted in maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj) and the dependency infrormation for a relevant version, such as the [4.8.0 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/4.8.2) that you are using can be found.

Comment: The dependency management system will ensure that all the correct transititive dependencies are also brought in, so you don't need to do that manually (removing a potential source of manual errors).  And you can easily switch versions if necessary by changing the version number listed for the dependency in your maven or gradle project definition file.  My comments are just opinionated suggestions for future work, your answer is already sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: You're correct. In fact, I was just struggling with module-related issues that were preventing me from compiling my project. I was aware of the utility that build tools provide, but I still haven't learned how to use them; all this time, I had been sourcing dependencies manually. I will now use Maven to save me the trouble and avoid problems like the one that initiated this post. Thanks for your guidance. As a beginner, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think this is not related to vlcj's optional native-streams library as such, rather it's that the native-streams library has brought in a different version of JNA as a dependency. Something has changed with the newer versions of JNA. You could not be using native-streams in your project, and still see this problem.

Comment: @caprica From what I understand, that means that certain versions of JNA may cause this problem, while others don't? How interesting.